# Implications of NL $\subseteq$ BQL/poly

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing, advice-and-nonuniformity

As far as I could see it's not known whether NL $\subseteq$ BQL/poly. Is it actually not known? If not, what would be the implications of the inclusion?